# How do I get my nav links in the nav bar?

Tags: html, css, position, navbar

I'm not sure why this is happening. The  tag that is the title "Don't Be Square" is in the nav bar, but not the links. What am I missing here in the CSS or the HTML that will bump it up inside there? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hG9eK.png)

Comment: Please add your html and css code for this.

Comment: can u plz add your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have header "Don't Be Square" after that you are righting code for Nav bar. And you wanted to bring your nav bar top right. To do so, you can right css for your title.
use **float: left;** there other way also you can acheive, for that you have to share the code.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some of the source code along with it. The only thing that I can potentially think of by just the image is that you are using some sort of header (h1, h2, etc) followed by some other tag that isn't inline (div, p, etc). Since both are block that could be why it displays on the line after. If this is the problem, a tags are inline so simply putting the  tags within the body of the h1 could suffice such as

```
<h1>Don't Be Square <a some link here/> <a another link/> <a third link></h1>
```

and then styling the links differently from the h1 by giving them an id or using the css identifier

```
h1 a{ your styling here}
```

Again I can't help much because there is no source but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example you may follow it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Don't Be Square</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float: right;">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  

</body>
</html>
```

View it in full screen if not the navbar will wrap. Good luck